# Multi-prover Interactive Proofs where the provers are working against each other

Tags: complexity-theory, interactive-proof-systems

I would like to know if there are any computational complexity classes where multiple provers interact with a verifier, but the provers work against each other.

For example, suppose it is a decision problem $A$. The verifier has to check if $x \in A$. There are two provers, $P_0, P_1$. $P_0$ tries to convince the verified $x \notin A$. Whereas $P_1$ convinces the verifier that $x \in A$. This problem seems to be somewhat associated with the Merlin-Arthur class, but I am not entirely sure if they are same.